# Windows form Chat tutorial

Tags: c#, winforms, chat

Ok i got a chat client now, now i just need some tips, how you get an client implement in it, so you can so who's online on the chat fore some guys that doesnt understand me.

Comment: "chat tutorial where you can see the online users ?" what do u mean by that... Please Elaborate your question a little more. Do you want to know how to make a Chat Client...

Answer (score 4):

First, have a look in to programming [sockets under C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsincsharp.aspx).  The IRC protocol is a simple text-based protocol that is easy to parse and respond to.

The IRC specification can be found [here](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/text/rfc1459.txt).

Additional specifications, [here](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/).

There are about as many ways to write a chat program as there are IRC networks!  Luckily, for someone exploring socket programming, an IRC client is a great start that you can get up and running easily in a console window before you plug in a GUI.

Comment: looks a litle hard, but nothing serious, it was just a question.